# Error al cargar la base de datos PM2

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu, pm2

Hola estoy desplegando mi primera aplicacion por medio de una VPS y no se porque mi app al ejecutarla con npm start [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ahi me carga perfecto pero cuando lo reinicio por PM2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me sale que no se puso conectar a la base de datos. Mi archivo se llama config.env y dentro de una carpeta config, es como si no pudiera acceder a ella desde PM2
este es mi archivo principal

```js
const app=require("./app")
const cloudinary= require("cloudinary")

//setear el archivo de configuracion
const  dotenv=require("dotenv");
const connectDatabase = require("./config/conexion");
dotenv.config({path: 'backend/config/config.env'})

//Conexion con la base de datos
connectDatabase();

//configurar cloudinary
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name:process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key:process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret:process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
})
//Inicializar el servidor 
app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`Servidor iniciado en el  puerto: ${process.env.PORT} en modo: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)
});
```

le he tratado de cambiar la ruta de dotenv.config({path: 'backend/config/config.env'}) por solo ./config/config.env o /backend/config/config.env pero cuando le cambio asi, ya no me funciona ni con npm start. Por favor pido ayuda, alguien

Comment: Hola. Debes crear un archivo que se llama ecosystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De algúna manera debes pasarle a PM2 tus variables de configuración. Una de estas opciones (para mi la más cómoda) es crear un fichero `ecosystem.config.js` y pasarlo como parametro.

Puedes generar uno de muestra con:

```
pm2 init simple
```

Te crea algo como esto:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : "app1",
    script : "./app.js"
    //AQUÍ VAN TUS VARIABLES DE AMBIENTE
    env: {
        PORT:9000,
        KEY_SECRETA:"MIQLAVEs3CR3T4"
    }
  }]
}
```

Y corres tu aplicación así:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

`app.js` es tu aplicación y debería estar a la misma altura que tu `ecosystem.config.js`

Para más información [da click aquí](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)